# Apache reverse SSL proxy fronting Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, mod-proxy, mod-ssl

I've ran into a problem using mod_proxy/mod_ssl. The Apache HTTP server on SLES 11 SP3 64 bit, OpenSSL 1.0.1.f acts as SSL proxy to the Weblogic 10.3 running on Redhat. The mod_ssl is configured correctly - it works when proxying to to non-ssl serves. Also, the certificate on the proxy was issued with extensions allowing it to be used as both SSL client and server.
Due the regulations servers in this organisation are not allowed insecure communication, so the proxy must use SSL communicating to the application serves.

The problem occurs with SSL handshake between Apache and Weblogic. Perhaps they can't agree on ciphers? What do those 7 bytes received indicate?

```
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [debug] mod_proxy.c(1036): Running scheme https handler (attempt 0)
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1995): proxy: HTTP: serving URL https://appdev2.example.com:8102/auth/logon.jsp?aa_param=user
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2022): proxy: HTTPS: has acquired connection for (appdev2.example.com)
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2078): proxy: connecting https://appdev2.example.com:8102/auth/logon.jsp?aa_param=user to appdev2.example.com:8102
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2236): proxy: connected /auth/logon.jsp?aa_param=user to appdev2.example.com:8102
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2487): proxy: HTTPS: fam 2 socket created to connect to appdev2.example.com
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2619): proxy: HTTPS: connection complete to 10.40.0.224:8102 (appdev2.example.com)
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [info] [client 10.40.0.224] Connection to child 0 established (server aaproxiedel1:443)
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [info] Seeding PRNG with 144 bytes of entropy
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1090): [client 10.40.0.224] SNI extension for SSL Proxy request set to 'appdev2.example.com'
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1903): OpenSSL: Handshake: start
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1911): OpenSSL: Loop: before/connect initialization
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1911): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1939): OpenSSL: read 7/7 bytes from BIO#994fe0 [mem: 9ea880] (BIO dump follows)
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1872): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1911): | 0000: 15 03 00 00 02 02 28                             ......(          |
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1917): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1916): OpenSSL: Read: SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1940): OpenSSL: Exit: error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [info] [client 10.40.0.224] SSL Proxy connect failed
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [info] SSL Library Error: 336032784 error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [info] [client 10.40.0.224] Connection closed to child 0 with abortive shutdown (server aaproxiedel1:443)
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [error] (502)Unknown error 502: proxy: pass request body failed to 10.40.0.224:8102 (appdev2.example.com)
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [error] [client 141.1.3.134] proxy: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /auth/logon.jsp
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [error] proxy: pass request body failed to 10.40.0.224:8102 (appdev2.example.com) from 141.1.3.134 ()
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2040): proxy: HTTPS: has released connection for (appdev2.example.com)
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1921): OpenSSL: Write: SSL negotiation finished successfully
    [Thu Sep 18 09:32:14 2014] [info] [client 141.1.3.134] Connection closed to child 2 with standard shutdown (server aaproxiedel1:443)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the things you can try is enabling "the WebLogic Plugin". This is in the Domain -> Configuration -> Web Applications and server -> General -> Advanced.. This enables all weblogic related plugins to work.

If this doesn't fix it, try to enable tunneling in protocols.

What do you see on the Weblogic logs? Both Access and the server log file?